# Create-react-app pagespeed confusion

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, nginx, pagespeed

I've been facing pagespeed problems using [this](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?hl=uk) tool from google

My goal is to reach ~95 on pagespeed insights;

I use create-react-app, and after I've:

- Enabled gzip in nginx for all project files,
- Compressed all images as suggested by Google,
- Used loadCSS polyfill to avoid css-blocking while page renders (I placed links of sanitize.min.css, and slick-carousel I use in public/index.html as suggested),
- Loaded fonts as suggested [here](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/512#issuecomment-322026199) using fontfaceobserver,
- Reviewed my css files, reduced amount of inline-css in js files to minimal

my current pagespeed is Medium(72) and Good(85) and PageSpeed Insights suggests to remove JS file which are blocking download (this is my main.js from react) and optimize CSS delivery (which is my main.css), and to make use of browser-caching (which I think is not the case here).

I seen similar questions and I tried to load pages as chunks using code-splitting (from [this tutorial](https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/code-splitting-in-create-react-app.html)) but it only reduced the pagespeed from what I have now, to 40-70 for mobile and for desktop respectively which makes no sense to me because why smaller chunks of code would do this? I also tried different approaches of react-router code-splitting but they didn't help to improve pagespeed at all, even worsen it.

I thought the issue might be that I

```
@import "material-components-web/material-components-web";
```

In my index.scss which is pretty heavy itself, I tried to import separate MDC packages but it didn't affected page speed at all. What can be done to reach desired 90+ pagespeed in my case? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well **create-react-app** is a broad starter project, meaning it is made with different things in mind, and with that, come **~50-100 dependencies** which most of them you probably don't need/use. Such a simple tool comes with it's downsides like this. If you are a beginner it is a very awesome tool to use, if you are advanced you'll see you have to eject to make more advanced config changes.

If you really need to tweak it for you every single need, you need to eject, then start by cutting off dependencies that you don't need, but if you are a beginner, I'd say stick with it.

I know this isn't a precise answer to your question, but broad questions receive broad answers :)

Comment: So I might want to switch to webpack instead of using react with create-react-app to achieve desirable pagespeed?

Comment: Well, yes, but that doesn't mean it gives you a instant boost. Again it's a broad answer, but you can give it a try. But don't eject from create-react-app because you will not be able to go back.

Comment: For my task, pagespeed insights results are a must, so I've ended up re-writing my landing without using webpack and reactjs (using gulp, express-handlebars); I figured that I won't find any reasonable tutorials on how to eject from CRA in order to improve pagespeed results. Anyway, thank you for your cooperation!